# how to fix #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed XAMPP in *localhost:8080* but I can't access *phpmyadmin* with a message error:

[image]

[ MySQL said: Documentation#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) ]

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

Open your MySQL console

For Xampp follow this guide [Access-mySQL-command-line-in-xampp](https://jamesdrakewilson.com/blog/2007/04/07/access-mysql-command-line-in-xampp/)

**Step 2**

Enter the Provided Command Lines
If you have a password, you can ignore this part.

Type in: `use mysql`;

Press Enter.

Set your MySQL Password:

```
UPDATE mysql.user
SET Password=PASSWORD("EnterYourPasswordHere")
WHERE User="root";
```

Replace "EnterYourPasswordHere" with your new chosen password.

Press Enter.

Flush the privileges: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`;

Exit by typing: Exit

Press Enter.

**Step 3**

Open and edit your `config.inc.php` file located in your local server files

Using a text editor, such as `Notepad++`, open your `config.inc.php` file.

Go to My Computer > `C Drive > (Your Local Server Folder, WAMP/MAMP/XAMPP) > APPS > PHPMYADMIN > config.inc.php`

Find this line of code: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';` // MySQL password

Change **password** to the new chosen password you created from Step 2.

Click Save.

**Step 4: Access phpMyAdmin**

You can access phpMyAdmin by going to http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/.

Congratulations! You are now able to access your databases.